# How sending files via Python Requests library is different to Curl?

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I need to upload file to Facebook via API. To do it i tried to use Curl and everything works great:

```
curl -F 'source=@/file.mp4' -F 'access_token=secret' https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/act_000042/advideos
```

Also i'm trying implement the same in Python using Requests:

```
    import requests # requests==2.19.1

    with open('/file.mp4', 'rb') as filecontent:
    response = requests.post(
       'https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/act_000042/advideos',
        data={
            'access_token': 'secret',
        },
        files={
           'source': filecontent,
        }
    )
```

And i get the same error: {'error': {'code': 1, 'message': 'An unknown error occurred'}.
So there is some difference between how Curl uploads files and how Requests uploads them.

What is the difference and how can i implement the same download via Requests?

Comment: Using `data=` leads to *post form*, i assume `access_token` have to be in `headers=` or in `files=`. Read [post-a-multipart-encoded-file](https://2.python-requests.org//en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)

Comment: @stovfl the same method works well for image upload

Comment: ***'An unknown error occurred'***: The error message tells nothing, are you sure the endpoint `v4.0/act_000042/advideos` is valid and accepts `.mp4`. I'm missing any `Content-Type` also.

Comment: ***"What is the difference"***: I have compared both, `curl`, `requests.post`, `header` and `fields` and found no differences.

Comment: I don't know graph.facebook.com, are you sure it accepts APIs? It might just be blocking you: [robots.txt](https://graph.facebook.com/robots.txt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so i figured out the difference is in Content-Disposition. Curl does not add anything if filename contains utf-8 symbols and content-disposition looks like:

`Content-Disposition: form-data; name="source"; filename="someunicodename..."`

Requests makes content-disposition according https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc5987.html and it looks like:

`Content-Disposition: form-data; name="source"; filename*=utf-8''someunicodename ...`

Facebook API does not understand rfc5987 specs and consider this content-disposition as inappropriate. Using only ASCII symbols in file name did solve the problem.